# Listing db elements

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting some data from a db.For all data found in first table is compared with data from second table.So I am retrieving ingredients stored in one table and those ingredients are compared with users favorite ingredients stored in second table.
    I want for each row that contains ingredients to list if there are the same ingredients as favorite ingredients.

Now I retrieve all data from db and the comparison is made for all ingredients, not for each one independently.

Here is my code:

```
    Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
               rs1 = st1.executeQuery("Select Nume from ingredientplacut where Id_user = '24'");
               while( rs1.next())
               {
                    String nrRet1 = rs1.getString("Nume");

                    secondList.add(nrRet1);

               }  
               System.out.println(secondList);

               Statement st = con.createStatement();
               java.sql.PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT ID_reteta,Nume,Descriere,Ingrediente,Mod_preparare,Dificultate,Tip,Imagini,Total_grasimi,Total_carbohidrati,Total_proteine,Total_calorii FROM reteta");
               rs=ps.executeQuery();                        

               while( rs.next()){
                   String nrRet = rs.getString("Ingrediente");

                   firstList.add(nrRet);

                   System.out.println("----");

               }  
                    ArrayList<String> al3= new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (String temp : firstList)
                    {
                        boolean isTrue=false;
                        for(String temp2:secondList)
                        {
                            if(temp.contains(temp2))
                            {
                                isTrue=true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(isTrue)
                            al3.add("YES");
                        else
                            al3.add("NO");
                    }

                      System.out.println(al3);
                      System.out.println(firstList);
                      ArrayList<Integer> al4= new ArrayList<Integer>();

                      for (String temp2 : secondList) {
                          boolean isTrue = false;
                          for (String temp : firstList) {
                              if (temp.contains(temp2)) {
                                  isTrue = true;
                                  break;
                              }
                          }
                          if (isTrue)
                              al4.add(1);
                          else
                              al4.add(0);
                      }

                      System.out.println(al4);
```

And the output is:

```
[afine, almette, alune, albus de ou de gaina, andive, mere]
----
----
[YES, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, YES]
[200 grame fusilli cu legume (afine,alune);
200 grame smantana 12%;
50 grame iaurt;
50 grame cascaval afumat ;
1/2 lingurite mustar;
doi catei de usturoi sau o lingurita de usturoi deshidratat;
mere;
patrunjel; 
piper;
sare., 250 grame dovleac ras; 
170 grame fulgi fini de ovaz; 
150 ml lapte dulce; 
80 grame stafide; 
un ou; 
doua linguri faina integrala; 
40 grame miere; 
un plic de zahar vanilat; 
½ lingurita scortisoara; 
afine;
putina sare., 4 medalioane de somon proaspat (aproximativ 800 grame); 
un ardei rosu mare; 
o lamaie mica; 
o rosie medie; 
putin patrunjel; 
4-5 catei de usturoi; 
doua lingurite capere;
2-3 linguri ulei de masline;
piper;
boia dulc;
sare., 150 grame maioneza de casa;
300 grame telina (net);
300 grame piept sau pulpe dezosate;
1/3 capatani usturoi;
marar si patrunjel dupa gust;
aprox 1/2 borcan castraveti murati in otet;
o lingura boia dulce;
½ lingurite piper;
10-20 ml ulei masline.
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

And I want the output be :

```
[200 grame fusilli cu legume (afine,alune);
200 grame smantana 12%;
50 grame iaurt;
50 grame cascaval afumat ;
1/2 lingurite mustar;
doi catei de usturoi sau o lingurita de usturoi deshidratat;
mere;
patrunjel; 
piper;
sare.
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] //3 ingredients related
 250 grame dovleac ras; 
170 grame fulgi fini de ovaz; 
150 ml lapte dulce; 
80 grame stafide; 
un ou; 
doua linguri faina integrala; 
40 grame miere; 
un plic de zahar vanilat; 
½ lingurita scortisoara; 
afine;
putina sare.,

[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] //one ingredient related
 4 medalioane de somon proaspat (aproximativ 800 grame); 
un ardei rosu mare; 
o lamaie mica; 
o rosie medie; 
putin patrunjel; 
4-5 catei de usturoi; 
doua lingurite capere;
2-3 linguri ulei de masline;
piper;
boia dulc;
sare.
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] //0 Ingredients related
 150 grame maioneza de casa;
300 grame telina (net);
300 grame piept sau pulpe dezosate;
1/3 capatani usturoi;
marar si patrunjel dupa gust;
aprox 1/2 borcan castraveti murati in otet;
o lingura boia dulce;
½ lingurite piper;
10-20 ml ulei masline.
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] //0 Ingredients related
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: I tried to wrap my head around your case, but I was not able to get the hang of the logic - most likely it's an example-data-overflow-error here. Could you try to boil down your case with only two favored ingredients + 5 ingredients in your DB in total? What's the expected result then? NB: I don't think that it's a good idea to code all this in Java. This sounds like a `join ` to me which the DB can do any time better (i.e. performing faster) than you could ever write it in Java...

Comment: How do you think I can do this using a Join, I was trying but I am not able to do that:(

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, if I get all the aspects fully right and my Romanian also is very bad, but here's what I got:
We have table called `ingredientplacut` which apparently list all ingredients, which the users like. We may assume

- that the name of the ingredient is stored in attribute `name` there,
- that the identifier of the user we are looking for is known
- that the attribute `user_id` of `ingredientplacut` provides the identifier of the user and thus is part of the primary key in this table.

The table `reteta` apparently provides the ingredients for a given recipe and appears to be denormalized (@Bogdan: if this isn't already a view on another DB tables, kindly check your relational data model. Otherwise, you highly risk to run into delete and update anormalies). The name of the ingredient there is stored in attribute `Ingrediente`.

The list of ingredients of the recipes can then be easily checked, if they are "favorite ingredients" by issuing the following join:

```
SELECT r.ID_reteta, r.Ingrediente, fav.name IS NOT NULL as isFavorite
FROM retata as r
LEFT JOIN inredientplacut as fav ON r.Ingrediente = fav.name
WHERE fav.user_id = '24'
```

Given this statement, it is also easy to determine the recipe with the "most liked" ingredients:

```
SELECT ID_retata, count(*) as favoriteIngredients
FROM (
    SELECT r.ID_reteta, r.Ingrediente, fav.name IS NOT NULL as isFavorite
    FROM retata as r
    LEFT JOIN inredientplacut as fav ON r.Ingrediente = fav.name
    WHERE fav.user_id = '24'
) as favlist
WHERE favlist.isFavorite = true
ORDER BY favoriteIngredients DESC
GROUP BY ID_retata
```

Please note, however, that this is a very bad performance indicator, as there is no weighting considered for the ingredients (I may like pepper and onions, but this doesn't mean that I like all the dishes where both of them is in...)

For sure, you may implement such a `LEFT JOIN` also on PHP level by reading only the source tables via SQL. However, I would try to avoid this due to multiple reasons:

- The DB optimizer is virtually not able to help you, so you need to be "better than the optimizer" - which I doubt that a interpreter-based language like PHP can be.
- You need to retrieve all the recipes (which might become a huge table) from the DB into PHP. So, your calculation is transferred through multiple stacks, the data types need to be verified and so forth. In short, your processing is "farer away" from the data - this is known to be slower by architecture.
- The coding is much worse to read and thus even worse to maintain. The SQL statement might not be too easy as well as it is more abstract, but by its descriptive nature, your intentions are visible in a more compact manner.

(NB: A seldom case, where more abstraction provides better performance - usually, mixing those two architectural concepts doesn't work out that well).